# Error while Packaging Project for Windows

Tags: unreal-engine4

The error with my textures, that are used for my HUD. I tried to change textures, but the result is same. They were imported from ordinary png images. What could go wrong?

> Texture Crosshair has source art in an invalid format.

Packaging log image:

[image]

Comment: What pixel format is the PNG texture?

Comment: @Rotem sry, I am a begginer, what is pixel format? and where can I find it? RGB 8-bit channel?

Comment: Yes, I mean the bit depth of the pixels. 8-bit PNG should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I make HUD from C++ I've created **UPROPERTY** from **UTexture2D**, when I change them to **Utexture** without 2D all works.